# PHP MYSQL QUERY FETCH FROM TWO TABLES

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, subquery

Please I'm new to PHP/MYSQL.
I have two tables. Table staff has (id, fullname) and Table attendance has (id,staff_id).
I intend to make a query to fetch all staff staff who do not have their id as staff_id in Attendance table. Below is my PDO code:

```
$att = $con->prepare('SELECT member_id FROM attendance');
$att->execute();
while ($att_fetch = $att->fetch()) {
$absent = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM members WHERE id != "'.$att_fetch['member_id'].'" ');
$absent->execute();
$absent_fetch = $absent->fetch();
echo '
  <tr>
   <td class="name" data-id="'.$absent_fetch['id'].'">'.ucwords($absent_fetch['fullname']).'</td>
  </tr> 
';
}
```

Surprisingly, this returns all staffs present in the Attendance table.
Please help me out

Comment: Why not use a `JOIN` for this?

Comment: I think your code has an SQLi vulnerability.

Comment: @Julia, pls show me how to prevent this from my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I intend to make a query to fetch all staff who do not have their `id` as `staff_id` in `attendance` table.

You don't need two queries plus some PHP logic for this. You can get the result that you want in a single query, using `not exists`:

```
select s.*
from staff s
where not exists (select 1 from attendance a where a.staff_id = s.id)
```